# How to add hours and minutes to date pattern?

Tags: html, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate an input field in which I set the date and time using a datetime picker. How can I add `h:m` to the pattern of the field so it's like `dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii`?

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="startDate" id="sDate" placeholder="Insert date..." pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}">
  <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Why can't you add the hours and minutes to the already existing regex? It's the exact same way you define stuff like the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want each part of the date/time in a capture group:

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.([0-9]{4}) ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/XkTfwo/11

Shortened the date part:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.([0-9]{4}) ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])
```

https://regex101.com/r/XkTfwo/12

Comment: That's a sloppy one. It also matches `11.11.1111 16:91`

Comment: 5-9 on the last part i think

Comment: Edited to only match valid times.

Comment: You also need to escape the periods, i.e. use `\.`

Answer (score 2):

the [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) attribute on a HTML `<input />` accepts a regular expression. Therefore one would need to create a regular expression for dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii. For example, a very rudimentary one could be (doesn't check that the month isn't between 01 and 12):

`[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}`

Please see [w3schools' tryit](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern).

EDIT: Note the escaped periods. These are necessary. See @glhr's answer for the enforcement of valid numbers for the fields (i.e. 01-12 for mm).

Comment: Good catch with the periods. However, your regex matches invalid dates/times eg. 00.00.0000 25:51

Answer (score 1):

The following should do:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.([0-9]{4}) ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])
```

Here you can try it: https://regex101.com/r/XkTfwo/10

Comment: Matches 11.11.1111 25:02